# UIWindow frame origin gets changed (unwanted) after entering background in iOS 16 Beta

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios16

My app has multiple windows. One of them used as tab bar (let's leave this specific thing out of discussion), so this window usually has `frame.origin = 50`.
Everything works fine, but in iOS 16 beta after entering background mode and coming back 'tabbar' window is fullscreen. This bug happens every single time.
Maybe Apple made some 'feature' or smth.
Anyone has any ideas ?